# call py_config() after loading reticulate library hangs

Tags: reticulate

I am trying to use reticulate from Rstudio to mix python and R calls

I have upgraded python to 3.6.5 and R to 3.5.3

library(reticulate)
py_config()

call to py_config() from the R console rever returns. I have to force quit the R studio process

Comment: R studio version is 1.2.1335

Comment: sys <- import("sys")
Error in py_set_attr_impl(x, name, value) : 
  Evaluation error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpytools'.